# Getting IllegalArgumentException while registering Oracle Service in Corda

Tags: corda

I have created Oracle service with @CordaService annotation

I am getting Exception while installing Corda Service.

It will not get defined service type, got size 0 in List object in first argument of constructor.

public NumberVerifierOracle(PluginServiceHub services){
    this(services.getMyInfo().serviceIdentities(NumberVerifierOracleType.getNumberVerifierOracleType().getServiceType()).get(0),services);
    }

The defined service type is:
public class NumberVerifierOracleType {
    private static ServiceType serviceType;
    private static NumberVerifierOracleType numberVerifierOracleType = new NumberVerifierOracleType();

```
private NumberVerifierOracleType(){
    serviceType = ServiceType.Companion.getServiceType("com.template.oracle.service","numberVerifierService_NumberVerifierOracle");
}

public static NumberVerifierOracleType getNumberVerifierOracleType() {
    return numberVerifierOracleType;
}

public ServiceType getServiceType() {
    return serviceType;
}
```

}

The Package hierarchy is:
com.template.oracle.service.NumberVerifierOracle class

Comment: Do you have your sourcecode anywhere I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have resolved this error by making service with Public modifier.

Like this:
public static ServiceType type;
static{
        type= NumberVerifierOracleType.getNumberVerifierOracleType().getServiceType();
 }

It will not work if we have private modifier and use directly getter method.
```